# Bad JavaScript Date Timestamps from Epoch in Firefox

Tags: javascript, date, firefox

I'm using Firefox on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine. I was tasked to fix a bug recently causing some bad local time stamps made by this code

```
var d = new Date(0);
d.setSeconds(epoch);
```

I don't know why it was written that way, is there a good reason to do that? If I set it directly using `new Date(epoch * 1000);` it will work and `setUTCSeconds` does also.

The second issue is that Firefox says "Eastern **Standard** Time" when it's really daylight time. Chrome doesn't do that.

Javascript is a language that I know of the basics to service a script, however, I come from C and C++. Is there something I'm missing here? I've reviewed `Date` and I can't figure out the best way to fix the code, or why it was written the way it was. All have the same `getTimezoneOffset`, as seen below.

```
var d = new Date(1476428709 * 1000);
alert(d.toTimeString());
```

> **Chrome**: 03:05:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time). valueOf: 1476428709000
>
> **Firefox**: 03:05:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time). valueOf: 1476428709000

```
var d = new Date(0);
d.setSeconds(1476428709);
alert(d.toTimeString());
```

> **Chrome**: 02:05:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time). valueOf: 1476425109000
>
> **Firefox**: 02:05:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time). valueOf: 1476425109000
>
> **Firefox** *using `setUTCSeconds`*: 03:05:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time): 1476428709000

---

**Edit: The daylight time issue appears to be a bug in Firefox:

[879261 – javascript seems to be using time zones backwards](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=879261)**

Comment: You seem to be getting the same timestamp, it's just the string representation that is different, which shouldn't really matter as you generally wouldn't use that for anything, you'd use the Date methods to get month, day, year etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was tasked to fix a bug recently causing some bad local timestamps made by code that is basically `var d = new Date(0); d.setSeconds(epoch);`. I don't know why it was written that way, is there a good reason to do that?

No. `new Date(millisecondsSinceEpoch)` is specified to work just fine. Perhaps it was a work around for a bug in a particular implementation.

> If I set it directly like Date(epoch * 1000) it will work and also setUTCSeconds.

When passing a single number value to the [*Date constructor*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-value), it's treated as UTC milliseconds since the epoch, so:

```
var d = new Date(number)
```

is equivalent to:

```
var d = new Date(0);
d.setUTCMilliseconds(number);
```

> The second issue is Firefox says Eastern Standard Time when it is Daylight time. Chrome doesn't do that.

The local time zone offset is determined from the host, it's independent of the language so may be an implementation issue.

When you do:

```
d.setSeconds(1476428709)
```

any overflow of the seconds is added to the rest of the date, it's not used as an offset from the epoch. So if *d* is a Date instance then:

```
d.setSeconds(1476428709);
```

and

```
d.setUTCSeconds(1476428709);
```

return identical results, e.g.

```js
var a = new Date();
var b = new Date(+a);
a.setSeconds(1476428709);
b.setUTCSeconds(1476428709);

console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: 1. Just to make clear, for the last example you are demonstrating what happens when the current date is created via `Date()` and then an arbitrary _n_ is added to that date?2. You are saying the inability of Firefox to display 'Eastern Daylight Time' is an implementation issue on their part? Were you able to reproduce the example I made? I'd like to have some confirmation before I file a bug.

Comment: I updated my question to note the second issue is a bug in Firefox. They are working on a fix for it.

Comment: 1. It's showing that adding to seconds or UTCSeconds is equivalent. That's not necessarily the case for minutes or hours since timezone offsets may affect those values. 2. The string produced by Date's *toString* is implementation dependent and does not necessarily include the time zone name at all (and there is no standard for such naming). Set your PC to some obscure time zone and see what happens. A Date should correctly adjust for the host timezone setting though, including daylight saving.